# How to restrict jquery dropdown and display only current and previous months dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display only current and previous month in the drop down list, and wanted to hide/remove the other months from the drop down. Additionally the default selection should be - to the current month

With below code I could achieve -

- Display months in drop down
- Default selection to current month
- Disable upcoming months

I am looking for:

- Default selection to current month
- Display only previous month in the drop down list

Could anyone please help or guide. Thanks in advance!!

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var curMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
  $('#monthsDropdown').prop('selectedIndex', curMonth);
  $('#monthsDropdown option:gt(' + curMonth + ')').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="monthsDropdown">
    <option value='1'>Janaury</option>
    <option value='2'>February</option>
    <option value='3'>March</option>
    <option value='4'>April</option>
    <option value='5'>May</option>
    <option value='6'>June</option>
    <option value='7'>July</option>
    <option value='8'>August</option>
    <option value='9'>September</option>
    <option value='10'>October</option>
    <option value='11'>November</option>
    <option value='12'>December</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated the question title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `css`, it will hide all next month

```
$('#monthsDropdown option:gt(' + curMonth + ')').css('display', 'none');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var curMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
  var preMonth = currentDate.getMonth() - 1;
  $('#monthsDropdown').prop('selectedIndex', curMonth);
  $('#monthsDropdown option:lt(' + preMonth + ')').css('display', 'none');
  $('#monthsDropdown option:gt(' + curMonth + ')').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="monthsDropdown">
    <option value='1'>Janaury</option>
    <option value='2'>February</option>
    <option value='3'>March</option>
    <option value='4'>April</option>
    <option value='5'>May</option>
    <option value='6'>June</option>
    <option value='7'>July</option>
    <option value='8'>August</option>
    <option value='9'>September</option>
    <option value='10'>October</option>
    <option value='11'>November</option>
    <option value='12'>December</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the code just hides months after the current month. 
Wanted to hide all month before previous months too

Comment: @JainPrince updated answer please check

Comment: Thanks, this is working

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var objMonthMapping = {
  1     : 'January',
  2     :   'February',
  3     :   'March',
  4     :   'April',
  5     :   'May',
  6     :   'June',
  7     :   'July',
  8     :   'August',
  9     :   'September',
  10    :   'October',
  11    :   'November',
  12    :   'December'
};

var intCurMonth     =   new Date().getMonth() + 1;

var intPrevMonth    =   (intCurMonth - 1) ? (intCurMonth - 1) : 12;

$('<option>').val(intPrevMonth).text(objMonthMapping[intPrevMonth]).appendTo('#monthsDropdown');
$('<option>').val(intCurMonth).text(objMonthMapping[intCurMonth]).appendTo('#monthsDropdown');

$('#monthsDropdown').val(intCurMonth);
});
```

This is the HTML:

`<div>
   <select id="monthsDropdown">
   </select>
</div>`

These lines of code is going to provide the option of current month and the previous month only, in the dropdown.

Comment: May I know the problem with the solution, I got down voted.

Comment: Perfect!!
Thank you @Atul Kumar Singh

Comment: Please upvote, if you find this useful. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.
Code:

```js
   

    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('select option').hide();
   var d = new Date();
   month = d.getMonth() + 1;
   $('select option[value='+month+']').attr("selected",true).prev().css( 
 "display", "block" );
  $('select option[value='+month+']').attr("selected",true).css( 
 "display", "block" );
});
```

```html
   

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div>
     <select id="monthsDropdown">
       <option value='1'>Janaury</option>
       <option value='2'>February</option>
       <option value='3'>March</option>
       <option value='4'>April</option>
       <option value='5'>May</option>
       <option value='6'>June</option>
       <option value='7'>July</option>
       <option value='8'>August</option>
       <option value='9'>September</option>
       <option value='10'>October</option>
       <option value='11'>November</option>
       <option value='12'>December</option>
     </select>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the code just hides months after the current month. Wanted to hide all month before previous months too